# ORA-00971: Missing SET keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I'm getting a confusing "**ORA97100 missing SET keyword**" error when trying to run this simple UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE 

    (SELECT
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.ID AS ID,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.TAHUN AS TAHUN,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.KODE_ANGGARAN AS KODE_ANGGARAN,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.JENIS_BIAYA AS JENIS_BIAYA,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.SUBTOTAL AS SUBTOTAL,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.TOTAL AS TOTAL,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.BELONGS_TO AS BELONGS_TO,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.NOMOR AS NOMOR,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.STATUS AS STATUS
  FROM WOS.RKAP_PROYEKSI
  LEFT JOIN WOS.RKAP_MASTER_KODE ON RKAP_MASTER_KODE.ID_KODE = RKAP_PROYEKSI.KODE_ANGGARAN
  LEFT JOIN WOS.RKAP_USER ON RKAP_USER.BIRO = RKAP_MASTER_KODE.BIRO
  WHERE TAHUN = '2018' AND RKAP_MASTER_KODE.BIRO = 'BSI') AS helper

  SET helper.STATUS = 0
```

I've also tried to erase the "AS", but still get in error.

Any well thought to advise will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think join in update in oracle doesn't work, You need MERGE statement.

Comment: I'm not sure that all versions of Oracle support this syntax.

Comment: That should work without the `as` (Oracle doesn't support the `as` keyword for table aliases, only for column aliases.) When I removed that, I got a *ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*, since I don't have your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WITH..AS` clause :

```
UPDATE RKAP_PROYEKSI R
   SET STATUS = ( 
WITH RP AS
(
SELECT
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.ID AS ID,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.TAHUN AS TAHUN,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.KODE_ANGGARAN AS KODE_ANGGARAN,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.JENIS_BIAYA AS JENIS_BIAYA,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.SUBTOTAL AS SUBTOTAL,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.TOTAL AS TOTAL,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.BELONGS_TO AS BELONGS_TO,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.NOMOR AS NOMOR,
      RKAP_PROYEKSI.STATUS AS STATUS,
      0 AS ZERO_STATUS
 FROM WOS.RKAP_PROYEKSI
 LEFT JOIN WOS.RKAP_MASTER_KODE ON RKAP_MASTER_KODE.ID_KODE = RKAP_PROYEKSI.KODE_ANGGARAN
 LEFT JOIN WOS.RKAP_USER ON RKAP_USER.BIRO = RKAP_MASTER_KODE.BIRO
WHERE TAHUN = '2018' AND RKAP_MASTER_KODE.BIRO = 'BSI')
SELECT RP.ZERO_STATUS
  FROM RP
 WHERE RP.ID = R.ID
)
```

Comment: This appears a bit awkward. Maybe run the CTE outside `SET`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can phrase this as:

```
UPDATE WOS.RKAP_PROYEKSI p
    SET STATUS = 0
    WHERE p.TAHUN = '2018' AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM WOS.RKAP_MASTER_KODE mk JOIN
                       WOS.RKAP_USER u
                       ON u.BIRO = mk.BIRO
                  WHERE mk.ID_KODE = p.KODE_ANGGARAN AND
                        mk.BIRO = 'BSI'
                 );
```

I don't see what `RKAP_USER` is being used for, but I left it in the query, just in case.

Comment: I'm still confused with "select 1", how could to do that? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @aldi . . . `exists` just checks for the existence of rows.  It doesn't matter what is being selected.  `1` is easy to type.